# Automatically log System.diagnostics.trace messages to an Nlog target

Tags: c#, trace, nlog, system.diagnostics

Say you have C# trace messages all over an application. Something like:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Service Started");
```

How do you automatically log this to an nLog target without having to add code like the following to all the classes that have trace messages?

```
using NLog;
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Is there a way to do this without including traces produced by the .NET Framework itself, which [this article](http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/02/routing-system-diagnostics-trace-and-system-diagnostics-tracesource-logs-through-nlog.html) demonstrates how to do?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NLog-Trace-Listener-for-System-Diagnostics-Trace

Answer (score 9):

This works for cases where there isn't an explicit source.

```xml
  <system.diagnostics>
      <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
        <listeners>
          <add name="MyNLogTraceListener" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
          <remove name="Default" />
        </listeners>
      </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use NLog's [NLogTraceListener](https://nlog-project.org/2010/09/02/routing-system-diagnostics-trace-and-system-diagnostics-tracesource-logs-through-nlog.html).

For completeness, here is the System.Diagnostics configuration (from the link above) to specify the NLogTraceListener:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="nlog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="nlog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You also need to configure NLog to tell it how to write the information once it moves from the System.Diagnostics.Trace to NLog:

```xml
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name="console" type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate} ${windows-identity} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nlog` as `<sharedListeners>` in the `App.config`

```xml
<system.diagnostics>

    <sources>
      <source name="System" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="nlog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="MySystem" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="nlog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="nlog" type="NLog.NLogTraceListener, NLog" />
    </sharedListeners>

    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="nlog" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
    
</system.diagnostics>
```

### Edit: using `TraceSource`

As `Nlog` comes with a `TraceListener` which can be used as shared listener, you can also add a custom soure `MySystem` as above you can get rid of `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();` and can use the build-in `TraceSource` itself as.

```cs
public class Person
{
//...
    var ts = new TraceSource("MySystem"); 
    //or ts = TraceSource(this.GetType().Name);
    ts.TraceInformation("This will go through nLog listener");
```

> This will avoid you to reference `nlog.dll` in each/every project in solution and will minimize the dependency to a single main project where `App.Config` resides.

Here with `TraceSource(this.GetType().Name)` you will achieve what `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` will do for you. And for `class Person` you need to add the following in the `App.Config` :

```xml
<source name="Person" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="nlog" />
    </listeners>
</source>
```

In turn now you can switch on/off logging from a module without rebuilding the whole solution.